# Two if statements (check width and scroll) not working

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have div-1 that I want to show only when div-2 has scrolled to the top. This is the code:

CSS

```
.none {display: none;}
```

jQuery

```
var distance = $('header').offset().top,
$window = $(window);
$window.scroll(function() {
if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
        $("#logo-menu").removeClass("none").addClass("animated fadeInLeft");
    } else {
        $("#logo-menu").addClass("none");
    }
});
```

And it's working fine. Additionally, I also want to show div-1 only for width > 900px, but I can't make it work. I tried this:

```
if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) && ($(window).width() > 960) {...}
```

But div-1 is showing on page load, even if div-2 hasn't scrolled to the top and regardless of screen width. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try this code first, is it working or not in your case: -   if ($(window).width() < 960) {
   alert('Less than 960');
}
else {
   alert('More than 960');
}

Comment: Yes, that code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave your javascript code as it is and use a media query in your CSS. Then be smart about which classes your are adding with javascript so that it they don't override the media query.

```
#div-1 { display: none; }

@media (min-width: 900px;) {

    #div-1 { display: block;  }

}
```

But aside from that, in your javascript that you posted in the question, this

```
if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) && ($(window).width() > 960) {...}
```

should be this:

```
if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance && $(window).width() > 960) {...}
```

You have your parenthesis in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you! I tried other variations but I never thought of checking the parenthesis :)